Trying to use league/container gives error
I am trying the example code from the container of thephpleague found at : https://container.thephpleague.com/4.x/ and what I have is pretty basic IMHO.
Note: PSR-4 auto loading has been configured in composer.json and composer du has been executed.
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

use App\Service\FooBar;
use App\Service\Bar;

$container = new \League\Container\Container(); 
$container->add('foobar', FooBar::class)->addArgument(Bar::class);
$container->add('bar', Bar::class);

$foo = $container->get('foobar'); //

The last line above gives an error:

Uncaught TypeError: App\Service\FooBar::__construct(): Argument #1 ($bar) must be of type App\Service\Bar, string given

The classes defined
// file: FooBar.php
namespace App\Service;

class FooBar {

    private $bar;

    /**
     * @param \App\Service\Bar $bar
     */
    public function __construct(Bar $bar) {
        $this->bar = $bar;
        var_dump('Constructor of '. __CLASS__ . ' called!');
    }

    public function getBar() {
        return $this->bar;
    }
}

//file: Bar.php
namespace App\Service;

class Bar {
    
    public function __construct() {
        var_dump('Constructor of ' . __CLASS__ . ' called!');
    }
}

If I register the following to the container I don't get an error.
$container->add(Bar::class);

I am trying to understand what is the problem with the first snippet which comes from the example code.

->addArgument(Bar::class) -- remove that. I'm just guessing, because I haven't used that particular DI container, but others I worked with looked at the constructor of FooBar in this case, found that it requires a Bar instance and fetched that from the container first. You overcomplicated it by adding a fixed argument that is misplaced here. BTW: Bar::class is a string, which is also what the message complains about.

If I do the above I get a diff error message - FYI
